# how to increase, decrease input quantity in cart shopify liquid

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

i have following code:

```
 <div class="quantity">
    <input type="number" name="updates[]" id="updates_{{ item.key }}" value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0">
 </div>
```

which increases input field value, but not product quantity in cart, how to fix it?

Comment: I'm having trouble to understandding your question. please share more details

Comment: @RomanGavrilov in my product card, there is a field for the quantity of the product, how can I make it change the name of the quantity, and not the number in the input, as it is now, and save it

Comment: normally quantity input tag's name should be 'quantity'.  If you want to keep it, you have to use the ajax

Comment: You need to add more details in order to answer the question. It sounds like there is some Javascript that is updating the input box but it is not AJAX POSTing to the backend. But this is hard to tell without more information.